# Constraints problem on scrolling view from stack view layout

Tags: layout, xamarin.ios

I'm having problems with the constraints on xamarin.ios, at the base I have a scrollingView and inside it many elements wedged into vertical and horizontal stackviews, sometimes more stack views overlap. I cannot post code because the constraints are set by the .storyboard file. When I have to set the constraints, then anchor constraints to the scrollingview by the stackviews, the problems begin, any point I insert and in any axis is not associated, but the current distance is set (constraint given by the position of the object in the viewcontroller) every now and then it becomes negative sometimes the bond remains for a few seconds then returns to mess up. I'm hoping it's a xamarin bug, so now I'm re-installing the IDE to remove any doubts, have you encountered similar problems, or scrolling view and stack layout view are not directly compatible, in case how did you solve the objects they must be necessarily grouped in a scrolling view.

[image]

Comment: It's hard for us to reproduce the issue through your description. This usually happens when you set the wrong constraints.

Comment: In this case, are there any rules to follow? for the management of constraints on scrolling views I mean. I noticed that by changing some circumstances the situation improves even if only slightly.

Comment: for example to attach the constraints I need a view pasted over the scrolling, it was not possible for me to get the constraints directly on the scrollign view.